# How to adjust datepicker view inside ag grid cell render template?

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

I use cell rendering in my ag-grid for editing a date field.Inside that cell datePicker is added as shown

[view of my cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVAyZ.png)

But when i am clicking the date icon date picker view is like it is fully mounded inside the cell and not visible properly.[the below picture shows my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoS0r.png)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gender-renderer',
  template: `  `
  <input type="text" id="recording_date_to" [(ngModel)]="changedRecDateTo" (change)="edit()"
  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" style="z-index: 0;"
  class="form-control input-sm" />
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
})
```

Tried z index , it is also not working..

Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Thank You in advance

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, to be able to use `DatePicker` in cell you need to create `cellEditor` instead of `cellRenderer`, however, `cellEditor` just like an extension for `cellRenderer`.

So for angular, you need to use `ICellEditorAngularComp` interface and take care of

```
agInit(params: any): void // for init value which would be used in DatePicker
```

and

```
getValue(): any // for passing value back to the grid (and update the cell)
```

*don't forget to return `true` in `isPopup(): boolean` method - for correct visibility.*

Now, about DatePicker itself, I'm using `@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker`

*(but for sure you can use anything)*

And there are a few things that you need to take care :

1. what type of value is the `datepicker` library using
2. what type of value you will use for view and for database

and it could be handled with `getValue` and `valueFormatter` methods

That's all for theory, check my demo below and feel free to ask anything related, will try to help.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-ag-grid-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

Two things...

First, if you are really using a date picker in a cell renderer, don't.
That should be done in a cell editor, not a renderer.

Second, if you want to have an editor that is not constrained by the cell,
you have to specify that the editor is a 'popup' editor by implementing `isPopup()` in your editor, and returning true.

The documentation for this is at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#popup

Comment: Thank you sir for spending your valuable time in this.
I have already tried date picker in cell editor,but it did'nt worked that's why i go for cell rendering..I will try once again,if not clearing my issue means will come up with a demo code ...:)

Comment: By the way, on my project, we never got a date picker working acceptably in the grid, and just went for a custom date editor that's a masked type-in field. Let me know if you want that code.

Comment: Can you please share that code?
It will be helpful for me to refer..

Comment: I posted the relevant code at https://github.com/rfreedman/ag-grid