# Ag Grid - React- Datepicker as cell editor not working

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to implement datepicker as cellEditor in AgGridReact. I tried following the below link : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-datepicker-cell-editing. But I am seeing an error when I copy the sample cell editor datepicker (using jQuery UI datepicker), the error message is "$" is not defined. I don't see any other sample code related to this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Update: 
The below question is related to Angular and I am using react as I have mentioned in my question. So, the questions are not related and the answers are not relevant
[How to adjust datepicker view inside ag grid cell render template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882662/how-to-adjust-datepicker-view-inside-ag-grid-cell-render-template)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust datepicker view inside ag grid cell render template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882662/how-to-adjust-datepicker-view-inside-ag-grid-cell-render-template)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. This seems to be related to Angular. Do you have any sample related to React? I couldn't find any

Comment: but it doesn't matter - you can anything that you wanted (reactjs,vuejs or angularjs), on the sample you have all that is required for datepicker implementation via ag-grid.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something here. The answer provided in the question which you have shared does not provide any insight into the problem I am facing. I don't see an approach either as to how I can go about it in React.

Comment: So, provide an example that you made and will check how I can help with it

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to finally create datepicker component in react using the sample mood editor component which ag grid had provided in their docs. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to install Jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-dist

1. npm i jquery
2. npm i jquery-ui
3. npm i jquery-ui-dist

and import

1. import $ from 'jquery';
2. import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker';
3. impoer 'jquery-ui-dist/jqueru-ui.css';

then it will work .......